# c# multi level json

Tags: c#, php, json

I am trying to make a simple program that can automate price checking using data from json, however I haven't used json before and I'm not quite sure what I need to do get get the desired result.

Effectively I'm trying to convert this PHP into c#. (http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/8042/api-json-parsing-php.html)

```
<?php
    $src = file_get_contents('https://www.g2a.com/marketplace/product/auctions/?id=256');
    $json = json_decode($src, true);
    foreach ($json as $k=>$v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            foreach($v as $key=>$value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    foreach($value as $arKey => $arValue) {
                        if ($arKey == 'p') {
                            echo $arValue . '<br/>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I've tried a few things such as `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(webJson)` and `JObject.Parse(webJson)`, but I'm just not sure where I should be looking or how to go about doing it.

I have the first part:

```
internal static string GetWebContent(string @ID)
        {
            var wc = new WebClient(); 
            string response = wc.DownloadString(@"https://www.g2a.com/marketplace/product/auctions/?id=" + @ID);
            return response;
        }
```

A response looks like this: (https://www.g2a.com/marketplace/product/auctions/?id=27446)

```
{"a":{"k_709942":{"c":"pl","tr":3451,"f":"\u00a324.71","fb":"\u00a327.18","ci":"565784","cname":"Marketplace User","p":"24.7098173","pb":"27.18431394","ep":"35.15","epb":"38.67","a":"709942","it":"game","t":"1","sl":"0","l":null,"lt":null,"x":0,"v":"all","so":0,"r":99},"k_763218":{"c":"pl","tr":1120,"f":"\u00a324.74","fb":"\u00a327.22","ci":"6533797","cname":"User #f36726dcd","p":"24.7449664","pb":"27.21946304","ep":"35.20","epb":"38.72","a":"763218","it":"game","t":"0","sl":"0","l":null,"lt":"0","x":0,"v":"all","so":0,"r":92},"k_799750":{"c":"pl","tr":559,"f":"\u00a324.78","fb":"\u00a327.26","ci":"6115711","cname":"Marketplace User","p":"24.7801155","pb":"27.26164196","ep":"35.25","epb":"38.78","a":"799750","it":"game","t":null,"sl":"0","l":null,"lt":null,"x":0,"v":"retail","so":0,"r":98},"k_722082":{"c":"gb","tr":49066,"f":"\u00a324.96","fb":"\u00a327.45","ci":"1047917","cname":"Marketplace User","p":"24.955861","pb":"27.4514471","ep":"35.50","epb":"39.05","a":"722082","it":"game","t":"1","sl":"0","l":null,"lt":"0","x":0,"v":"all","so":0,"r":98},"k_718113":{"c":"pl","tr":5852,"f":"\u00a324.96","fb":"\u00a327.45","ci":"226876","cname":"Marketplace User","p":"24.955861","pb":"27.4514471","ep":"35.50","epb":"39.05","a":"718113","it":"game","t":"1","sl":"0","l":null,"lt":"0","x":0,"v":"all","so":0,"r":98},"k_739155":{"c":"pl","tr":1208,"f":"\u00a325.43","fb":"\u00a327.98","ci":"6540559","cname":"User #1f948a6a66249","p":"25.43316468854","pb":"27.976481157394","ep":"35.30","epb":"38.83","a":"739155","it":"game","t":"0","sl":"0","l":null,"lt":"0","x":0,"v":"all","so":0,"r":89},"k_795049":{"c":"pl","tr":50420,"f":"\u00a325.86","fb":"\u00a328.45","ci":"2498689","cname":"Marketplace User","p":"25.86270778","pb":"28.44968154","ep":"36.79","epb":"40.47","a":"795049","it":"game","t":"1","sl":"0","l":null,"lt":"0","x":0,"v":"all","so":0,"r":99},"k_816132":{"c":"pl","tr":22,"f":"\u00a326.00","fb":"\u00a328.60","ci":"6208533","cname":"Marketplace User","p":"25.99627436","pb":"28.59730776","ep":"36.98","epb":"40.68","a":"816132","it":"game","t":"0","sl":"0","l":null,"lt":"0","x":0,"v":"retail","so":0,"r":0},"k_809925":{"c":"pl","tr":81021,"f":"\u00a326.00","fb":"\u00a328.60","ci":"407513","cname":"Marketplace User","p":"26.00330418","pb":"28.60433758","ep":"36.99","epb":"40.69","a":"809925","it":"game","t":"1","sl":"0","l":null,"lt":"0","x":0,"v":"retail","so":0,"r":100},"k_815898":{"c":"cl","tr":1,"f":"\u00a326.01","fb":"\u00a328.61","ci":"7524623","cname":"Marketplace User","p":"26.010334","pb":"28.6113674","ep":"37.00","epb":"40.70","a":"815898","it":"game","t":null,"sl":"0","l":null,"lt":null,"x":0,"v":"retail","so":0,"r":0},"k_711901":{"c":"pl","tr":12194,"f":"\u00a326.51","fb":"\u00a329.16","ci":"286793","cname":"Marketplace User","p":"26.506689203722","pb":"29.158078610346","ep":"36.79","epb":"40.47","a":"711901","it":"game","t":"1","sl":"0","l":null,"lt":null,"x":0,"v":"all","so":0,"r":99},"k_748710":{"c":"pt","tr":66460,"f":"\u00a326.65","fb":"\u00a329.32","ci":"440288","cname":"Marketplace User","p":"26.650786454082","pb":"29.316585585742","ep":"36.99","epb":"40.69","a":"748710","it":"game","t":"1","sl":"0","l":null,"lt":"0","x":0,"v":"all","so":0,"r":100},"k_709464":{"c":"pl","tr":121341,"f":"\u00a327.02","fb":"\u00a329.72","ci":"1072530","cname":"User #3285e5f8dfcb2","p":"27.0182344425","pb":"29.72005788675","ep":"37.50","epb":"41.25","a":"709464","it":"game","t":"1","sl":"0","l":null,"lt":"0","x":0,"v":"retail","so":0,"r":100},"k_709805":{"c":"pl","tr":11708,"f":"\u00a328.09","fb":"\u00a330.90","ci":"1043113","cname":"User #ca1965d0354a","p":"28.091758957682","pb":"30.901655339702","ep":"38.99","epb":"42.89","a":"709805","it":"game","t":"1","sl":"0","l":null,"lt":null,"x":0,"v":"retail","so":0,"r":100},"k_725839":{"c":"es","tr":1,"f":"\u00a331.99","fb":"\u00a335.18","ci":"7023396","cname":"Marketplace User","p":"31.985681","pb":"35.1842491","ep":"45.50","epb":"50.05","a":"725839","it":"game","t":null,"sl":"0","l":null,"lt":null,"x":0,"v":"retail","so":0,"r":0},"k_0":{"f":"\u00a332.33","fb":"\u00a335.56","p":"32.33014218","pb":"35.563156398","ep":"45.99","epb":"50.59","a":0,"c":"","rc":"","r":"","tr":0,"t":1,"so":0,"x":0,"n":"G2A.com"}},"w":0}
```

Any help with will greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advace

Comment: you don't "deal with json". json is wrapping paper, used to encapsulate/wrap some data. you decode that json into a native data structure, and then it's no longer json - it's native data and you deal with it like you would any other native data.

Answer (score 0):

So Json is a way for two languages to pass objects to each other.  It's just a way to encode an object, so the first part would be to create an object that matches the Json encoding.  I was unable to see your example, so I will give you one of my own.

```
{"Aggregates": [{"ColumnName": "Some Value", "AggregateFunction": "Some Other Value"}], "GroupBy": true}
```

I would then create a class like this one.

```
public class JsonAggregates
{
    public List<Aggregate> Aggregates { get; set; }
    public string GroupBy { get; set; }
}

public class Aggregate
{
    public string ColumnName {get; set;}
    public string AggregateFunction {get; set;}
}
```

You can then encode the Json to this new data type with the following code.

```
using (Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString(json))
{
      DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonAggregates));
      JsonAggregates aggregate = (JsonAggregates)serializer.ReadObject(s);
}
```